# Script not working after index mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have a simple table with `id|id_account|type|user` all work but after i indexed "id_account" with `UNIQUE` my script not work with EDIT (but work with INSERT)

id_account is a sha256 like this format: 8a9a9a9b63617d857... 
What is the good index for that ?

I need to drop all and reindex yes ?

Thanks (sorry for my little english)

Comment: Show your script please. It is hard to say something unknown code.

Comment: sorry i have long script and i dont know here is error ... because i start without index and in mysql log i dont have error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIQUE is not only index but also constraint. Not sure what you calls "EDIT" but believe your issue deals with that constraint, and you making duplicated values for that constraint. (ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html)

possible issue - you making table update (EDIT) with wrong WHERE clause, which causes modification of more than one record in your table with same id_account value - and this is not allowed since you using UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Ah ok if i use simple INDEX is good ? Or i change id_account with INT ?

Comment: for a format like '8117b84373151a22146ae072414f5d82f2ad811414b6d6b24f85803640bde4c8' normal index is good ?

Comment: "for a format like '8117b84373151a22146ae072414f5d82f2ad811414b6d6b24f85803640bde4c8' normal index is good ?"
"Or i change id_account with INT ?" - definitely INT index will work faster - but I do not believe you will be able to fill it without profiling on your simple table...

Comment: Thanks you its work great with INDEX u right its because i have double in my database Thanks you again